# Weekly group assignment algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

A friend of mine who who is a teacher has 23 students in a class. They want an algorithm that assigns students in groups of 2 and one group of 3 (handle the odd number of students) across 14 weeks such that no two pairs repeat across the 14 weeks (a pair is assigned to one week).

A brute force approach would be too inefficient, so I was thinking of other approaches, matrix representation sounds appealing, and graph theory. Does anyone have any ideas? The problems that I could find deal only with 1 week and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586587/combinatorial-algorithm-for-assigning-people-to-groups) I could quite figure out.

Comment: Please clarify - 'no two pairs repeat across the 14 weeks' - different pairs every day or different pairs every week?

Comment: @Serg pairs are assigned on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Round-robin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm) will do the trick i think.

Add the remaining student to the second group and you are done.

```
First run
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
23  22  21  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13

Second run
1   23  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  
22  21  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13  12
```

...

Comment: +1 Far more elegant than the other suggestions, plus randomized initial lists will give us random pairings.

Comment: Best solution here: you're linking to a page that explains the algorithm so they can implement it themselves and showing the example of the runs so the final result is clear.

Comment: @solidrevolution It only works with even number of students. Odd number of students doesn't work tried matching the last one with the second group and many other ways it didn't work, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility might be [graph matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29), 14 distinct graph matchings would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to describe the problem in terms of constraints.

Then pass the constraints to a tool like ECLiPSe (not Eclipse), see http://eclipseclp.org/.

In fact, your problem seems similar to that of the Golf example on that site (http://eclipseclp.org/examples/golf.ecl.txt).

Comment: Hm, doesn't integer constraint programming have pretty abysmal run times? I thought I remembered something there.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Constraint programming environments have rules to lead the application to the solution, rather than using the brute-force approach that simply iterates over all dimensions.  E.g. in the 8-queen problem, the constraint engine will typically loop over the dimension with the smallest resulting domain.

Answer (score -1):

Start off with a set (maybe a bitset mapping to students for less memory consumption) for each student that has all other students in it. Iterate 14 times, each time picking 11 students (for the 11 groups you will form) for whom you will pick partners. For each student, pick a partner they haven't been in a group with yet. For one random student of those 11, pick a second partner, but make sure no student has less remaining partners than there are iterations left. For every pick, adjust the sets.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example in Haskell that will produce groups of 14 non-repeating 11-pair-combinations. The value 'pairs' is all combinations of pairs from 1 to 23 (e.g., [1,2], [1,3] etc.). Then the program builds lists where each list is 14 lists of 11 pairs (choosing from the value 'pairs') such that no pair is repeated and no single number is repeated in one list of 11 pairs. It's up to you to simply place the missing last student for each week as you see fit. (It took about three minutes to calculate before it started to output results):

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

pairs = nubBy (\x y -> reverse x == y) 
        $ filter (\x -> length (nub x) == length x) $ replicateM 2 [1..23]

solve = solve' [] where
  solve' results =
    if length results == 14
       then return results
       else solveOne [] where
         solveOne result =
           if length result == 11
              then solve' (result:results)
              else do next <- pairs
                      guard (notElem (head next) result' 
                             && notElem (last next) result'
                             && notElem next results')
                      solveOne (next:result)
                         where result' = concat result
                               results' = concat results
```

One sample from the output:

```
[[[12,17],[10,19],[9,18],[8,22],[7,21],[6,23],[5,11],[4,14],[3,13],[2,16],[1,15]],
[[12,18],[11,19],[9,17],[8,21],[7,23],[6,22],[5,10],[4,15],[3,16],[2,13],[1,14]],
[[12,19],[11,18],[10,17],[8,23],[7,22],[6,21],[5,9],[4,16],[3,15],[2,14],[1,13]],
[[15,23],[14,22],[13,17],[8,18],[7,19],[6,20],[5,16],[4,9],[3,10],[2,11],[1,12]],
[[16,23],[14,21],[13,18],[8,17],[7,20],[6,19],[5,15],[4,10],[3,9],[2,12],[1,11]],
[[16,21],[15,22],[13,19],[8,20],[7,17],[6,18],[5,14],[4,11],[3,12],[2,9],[1,10]],
[[16,22],[15,21],[14,20],[8,19],[7,18],[6,17],[5,13],[4,12],[3,11],[2,10],[1,9]],
[[20,21],[19,22],[18,23],[12,13],[11,14],[10,15],[9,16],[4,5],[3,6],[2,7],[1,8]],
[[20,22],[19,21],[17,23],[12,14],[11,13],[10,16],[9,15],[4,6],[3,5],[2,8],[1,7]],
[[20,23],[18,21],[17,22],[12,15],[11,16],[10,13],[9,14],[4,7],[3,8],[2,5],[1,6]],
[[19,23],[18,22],[17,21],[12,16],[11,15],[10,14],[9,13],[4,8],[3,7],[2,6],[1,5]],
[[22,23],[18,19],[17,20],[14,15],[13,16],[10,11],[9,12],[6,7],[5,8],[2,3],[1,4]],
[[21,23],[18,20],[17,19],[14,16],[13,15],[10,12],[9,11],[6,8],[5,7],[2,4],[1,3]],
[[21,22],[19,20],[17,18],[15,16],[13,14],[11,12],[9,10],[7,8],[5,6],[3,4],[1,2]]]
```

Comment: Now explain which algorithm it's using and exactly what it's doing.