# I have seating arrangement/math issues

Tags: math, distribution, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

Its easier for me to describe this in sports terms...
Let's say I have a league where players compete against each other in 2 teams of 2 with RANDOM partners. They will then play 3 games:
Ex: 
Court 1 has players A, B, C, and D: **ABvsCD then ACvsBD then BCvsAD**.

If I have 20 people in this league, and the league will go 24 weeks. How can I make sure that number of times that any 2 people end up on the same court as eachother MULTIPLE TIMES is distributed evenly amongst everyone?!

Comment: Try mathematics.stackexchange

Comment: How many games per week?

Comment: Each individual will play one a court of 4 for 3 games. using each player on that COURT as their partner ONE TIME each

Comment: This question reminded me of [this other question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823106/weekly-group-assignment-algorithm-with-odd-number-of-participants)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to minimize the sum of the square of the number of times 2 players play against each other.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB2CxfLhHG4) which explains how to implement such a fairness (or load balancing) constraint on a tennis scheduling problem at about 7 minutes into the video.

The example does both "number of times they play" fairness and "confrontation" fairness. Your description seems to indicate you're looking for "confrontation" fairness.